# Maven clean install not including sqlite dependency for executable jar file

Tags: java, maven, sqlite, executable-jar

After using

```
mvn clean install
```

and then

```
java -jar executable.jar
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>****</groupId>
<artifactId>****</artifactId>
<version>0.7-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>****</name>
<description>****</description>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit/junit5-engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit5-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0-ALPHA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tinyjee.jgraphx/jgraphx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tinyjee.jgraphx</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgraphx</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1.3</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>******</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>*****</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>******</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Running the program inside intelliJ works without problems. I included it there from the project structure.

I replaced names and directories with ****. This is a school project and I don't want my prof accusing me of providing solutions to other groups in case they find this stackoverflow entry.

Comment: IDEs (IntelliJ, Eclipse, etc) often set up the application classpath behind the scenes, that's why it works in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are getting this only when you are running your jar **because the dependencies are not available/packaged inside of it**.

Try generating a **"fat jar"** (also known as **uber-jar**), it will package all your dependencies inside the jar:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>YOUR_JAR_FINAL_NAME</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Documentation related to the `maven-shade-plugin` can be [found in here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/usage.html)

Since you are using a runnable jar file, you can follow [this section of the documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) related to *Executable Jars*

Comment: The `maven-assembly-plugin` is also useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Some background.
Maven install never installs dependencies;
it only installs the project that is build via the POM.
The installation of dependencies are a task that you must also perform
if you don't use either a "fat jar" (which I can't recommend) or use
the new spring boot executable jar implementation.

The classic "fat jar" is an amazingly terrible
(but often the only option)
solution for a problem like this.

Consider using Spring-Boot;
they have developed a new,
sane,
version of an executable jar file that includes the dependencies within the executable jar and adds them to the classpath at startup.
This functionality is similar to the functionality of a "war" file when it is added to
a JEE container.

Caveat: I don't work for Pivotal,
I just like much of their work (the Spring Framework).

Edit:
Here is a link to the
[Executable Jar Section in the Spring Boot Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar).
It contains some details.

Comment: I already have generated both jars using the fat-jar approach and some other jars using Spring Boot but you pointed something interesting, is there any difference between these two packagings when handling a jar specifically? I just checked and there are a few Boot classes inside the jar, but never questioned the essence of the structure itself